# PrimeNG - MultiSelect with user confirmation

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I have a `multiSelect` component and I want whenever user changes its selected options to show a confirmation message, asking whether they want to proceed with that change or not and according to their answer rollback changes or apply them.

Unfortunately I did not find any **built-in** functionality to achieve this, is there any way I can apply the functionality described above during the `(onChange)` event?

**Example**:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="availableLanguages" [(ngModel)]="languages" 
                               name="languages"
                               (onChange)="myChangeFunction($event);"
                               class="multiselect-custom">


myChangeFunction(event: any) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure?',
    acceptLabel: 'Yes',
    rejectLabel: 'No',
    accept: () => {
       // do that change if user presses "Yes"
    },
    reject: () => {
      // rollback the change if user presses "No"
    }
  });
 }
```

**Angular version: 12.2.3**

**PrimeNG version: 12.1**

Comment: So your question is the confirm dialog not showing? Or?

Comment: No, the confirm dialog is shown file, but the multiselect changes before the user gives permission in the confirmatonDialog, I have made a solution which rollbacks the change in case the user does not give his permission by keeping a copy of the values before multiselect change event takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as described in the comments section, I ended up doing a custom solution to solve this problem, by keeping a copy of the values before the multiselect `change` event takes place so that **if the user gives permission** on the confirmation dialog shown, **we keep the changes** and **if the user does not give permission** on the confirmation dialog, **we rollback the changes** by **setting to the actual value the previous copy**.

Code Example shown below:

**.html file**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="availableLanguages" [(ngModel)]="languages" 
                           name="languages"
                           (onChange)="myChangeFunction($event);"
                           class="multiselect-custom">
```

**.ts file**

```
languages = [....]; // this is our variable carrying the actual values
languagesCopy = []; // this is our "copy-variable" helper for rollback  


ngOnInit(): void {
  // initialize the "languagesCopy" to have same value with "languages"
  this.languagesCopy = this.languages;
}

myChangeFunction(event: any) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure?',
  acceptLabel: 'Yes',
  rejectLabel: 'No',
  accept: () => {
   // do nothing since the change has already take place
 },
 reject: () => {
  // rollback the change if user presses "No"
  // "languages" have already changes since it is binded through 
  //  [ngModel] from the multiSelect change event, so set the languages 
  //  variable back to its previous value stored in "languagesCopy"
   this.languages = this.languagesCopy;
 }
 });
}
```

I do not know if there is any better way to achieve the scenario described above but this solution works fine for my case :)